# Mongoose: How to set _id manually before saving?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

With the following code given:

```
const schema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    }
}

schema.pre('validate', (next) => {
    console.log(this.name);
    this._id = crypto.createHash('md5').update(this.name).digest("hex");
    next();
});

const myObject = new MyObject({ name: 'SomeName' });
myObject.save();
```

The application throws this error message:

```
MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving
```

My Question is, how is it possible to set the _id manually for a model?

And why is this.name undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(next) => ...` is arrow function where `this` is lexical and refers to enclosing scope, which is `module.exports` in Node.js module scope.

In order to get dynamic `this` inside a function, it should be regular function:

```
schema.pre('validate', function (next) { ... })
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the arrow function. Works like a charm now!